# Better Hive-Spark connection?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am reviewing an old Spark software that must to run many small queries and counts (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t`) in parallel and using direct Hive-SQL.

In the past the software solved its "problems with parallelize queries" by running each by [Beeline](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Beeline%E2%80%93CommandLineShell) on shell (`sys.process._`). I can't  use modern fresh Spark, at this moment only Spark v2.2.  The fragments bellow illustrate the full SQL-query methods.

There are a "Spark way" to access Hive and run SQL queries with (little) better performance and better reuse of the Spark configurations?  
**No risk to lost** pure-Hive or parallelization with native Hive-Spark?

---

### Illustrating

```
package br.com.generaldq.utils

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

object HiveUtils {

  val log: Logger = Logger.getLogger(HiveUtils.getClass)

  def beelineExec(hql: String, queue: String = "DataQuality"): String = {
    // here the beeline call and parameters are fixed, 
    // no reuse of Spark configurations.
    val serversHive=List("etc:2181", "etc2:2181")
    log.info(hql)
    val bl =
      Seq("beeline", "-u", "'jdbc:hive2://etcEtc","--hiveconf","... ETC...", "-e",
        "\""+hql+"\""
      )
    import sys.process._
    var result =
      try {
         Process(bl).!!
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          log.error(s"Error '${e}' on executing Hive query.\nQuery: ${hql}\n")
          s"Error on executing Hive query. Query: ${hql}"
      }
    result
  }

}
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: Hi @mazaneicha I edited to show the point: no risk?

Comment: I think that is not the connection itself. I added some info.

Comment: After migration to Spark native I'd expect to see from better to superior performance compared to Hive on MR. Re. connection - HiveServer2 by itself is a major bottleneck and resource hog when it comes to concurrent queries.

Comment: As @mazaneicha stated, drift away from Hive definitely as soon as you can, if you can. Native Spark is a no brainer in terms of performance if tuned correctly

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what platform you are in, but in case of HDP you can use the Spark Warehouse Connector to access hive. I would expect good performance while still leveraging the Metadata management of Hive and even security policies set on a table/column level.

Here is the documentation: 
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html

If you don't have an integrated platform you can sometimes get performance by avoiding hive and just giving full access to the warehouse directory on Hdfs, of course this may create security concerns.

Comment: Thanks Dennis (!), I edited, is Spark 2.2 and all other (not so old) software is using Scala-Spark 2.2.. The point in the question is about "*risk* of losing performance".

Comment: Then probably you won't find anything with performance other than with the alternative I mentioned in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Hive on Spark connectivity to run Spark SQL. 
https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/admin_hos_oview.html

Second method is Spark Thrift server - see for example 
https://mapr.com/docs/61/Spark/SparkSQLThriftServer.html 
how to get it running (notice Spark's doesn't come with Thrift Server by default, and you may have to rebuild your Spark to get this added `-Phive-thriftserver`).

Third method is Apache Livy. Recent release 0.6 of Livy has added Thrift Service too. 
This method is comparable to native Spark Thrift Service.

In terms of performance all these options are similar / same.

Although if you're on CDH5 for example, CDH5's Hive is hardwired to use Spark 1 to run so there is an indirect penalty there as you miss those Spark 2 improvements. 
CDH6 doesn't have this issue.

Notice that it's not clear from your question why you had to use Hive. 
You can use Spark SQL directly - through methods 2 and 3 described above.

If you have to have Spark SQL access from your Java/Scala applications, you can have direct JDBC connections to Spark through Thrift Server / Livy Thrift Server.

As far as performance is concerned, another aspect to keep in mind is how many concurrent connections you expect. Hive on Spark (method 1), and Spark Thrift Server (method 2) create a separate Spark session for each user so 1) there is a penalty to create a new connection and 2) it doesn't scale well in terms of how many users this architecture can support.

Livy Thrift Server on the other hand allows to take advantage of Spark's FAIR scheduler (basically, you can have multiple Spark queries/jobs running at the same time in the same single Spark session, may need a manual build, see https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy/pull/135 ).